# Gazebo11 is always using default materials on Heightmaps?

Tags: gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So I am having some problems getting the texture to show up correctly for a heightmap tag. And I am now having doubts about the example and tutorial. Looking at the example worlds/heightmap_dem.world, and it looks like this: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/raw/default/dem/files/gazebo_sthelens.png But the sdf has 3 different textures added, that are supopsed to change depending on height. Why does the example show only one texture? Also if I change texture just to bricks, doesn't seem to have any affect. I have tested this in gazebo-11

This is on Ubuntu 18.04, default install with Ogre 1.9.0

[C:\fakepath\Annotation 2020-04-16 080059.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15870385143193747.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24771/gazebo11-is-always-using-default-materials-on-heightmaps?/) by [LakeWorthB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24412/lakeworthb/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 45 on 2020-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There might be a problem in how you are running the example, because I get the following output:

[C:\fakepath\Screen Shot 2020-04-08 at 11.24.13 AM.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1586369980925008.png)
[image: image description]

Did you set GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH to point to the location of these textures?
For gazebo9 I need to set the variable as follows before starting the simulation:

```
GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-9 gazebo <path-to>/volcano.world
```

Try to find where these textures are located on your machine and make sure GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH points there

---

Originally posted by [Samahu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25193/samahu/) with karma: 56 on 2020-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LakeWorthB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24412/lakeworthb/) on 2020-04-16**:
So thanks for your reply, and it led me to find 2 issues.

1. One, the default DEM in gazebo-11 hangs off so far off the side that I didn't notice before, and which has the gradient, but is below the actual volcano, see my screenshot.
2. I then changed the top material listed int he world file to be bricks.png and it looks exactly the same, and then I even deleted all the material section, and it looks exactly the same, with the same gradient, which I guess is the default.

**Comment by [LakeWorthB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24412/lakeworthb/) on 2020-04-16**:
Found the overall problem, needed to delete the cache as it includes textures.

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2020-05-27**:
I've tried the same, and it failed miserably. I used heightmap_dem.world. which comes with gazebo and it complains about the heightmapdata size must be square.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

i found the overall problem, I needed to delete the cache when changing textures.

---

Originally posted by [LakeWorthB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24412/lakeworthb/) with karma: 45 on 2020-04-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hawkinator](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/57116/hawkinator/) on 2021-10-05**:
Exactly to be more precise, you need to delete the .gazebo/paging files.